# Accessing posted ajax data showing empty post data

Tags: php, ajax

I have the following code that fires off after an onclick event in my index.php file. However when i try to acces the data posted in page2.php I get an empty array .

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "page2.php",
    type: "post",
    data: 6 ,
    success: function (data) {
     alert(data);

    },
    error: function() {
              alert('failure');;
    }


});
```

In my php code i  have the following;

```
$x = $_POST['data'];
echo = $x;
```

Even when i print out the $_POST is give me an empty array

Comment: `echo = $x;` seams pretty wrong if it's your real code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP will populate `$_POST` with URL encoded or Multipart form encoded data. You are sending neither.

You should encode your data instead of sending a plain text string.

In your JS:

```
data: { myNumber: 6 },
```

(jQuery will convert an object of data to URL encoded data by default)

In your PHP:

```
$x = $_POST['myNumber'];
echo $x;
```

---

If you really want to send a plain text string, then you should say so in the request:

```
data: 6 ,
contentType: "text/plain"
```

and then you need to process the body of the request manually:

```
$x = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: I am still geting an empty array. The data shows up in an alert when i print the entire html in an alert i can see it because the success function goes off, hoever it doesnt actually show in my html

Comment: @Derek — Why would it show in your HTML? Your code alerts it (and you say that you see it in the alert) but your code doesn't put it in the HTML.

Comment: How can i access the variable then, i cant get to it in my page2.php with $_POST['myNumber'];

Comment: @Derek — You said it was showing up in the alert. Since the alert shows you the output of `page2.php` you **are** accessing the variable. If you want to load `page2.php` as a new page … then don't use Ajax. The whole point of Ajax is that it makes HTTP requests without loading a whole new page.

Comment: I only want to access the 1 variable $_POST['myNumber'];  in my page2.php thats all

Comment: @Derek — As I said. You **are** doing that successfully.

Comment: how? its not showing up in my page2.php wnhen i try to print the variable

Comment: @Derek — You said "The data shows up in an alert when i print the entire html in an alert i can see it". Since the alert is showing page2 … it is showing up.

Comment: Unless you mean that: After looking at the alert, you make a new request to page2.php, and it doesn't show up there. In which case, why would it? You've made a new request which doesn't have the data in the request, so when page2.php runs *again* with *different input* it gives different output.

Comment: I only see it in the alert, when the alert goes away the page is shown but without the variable being printed

Comment: See my previous comment. You have some other code which makes **another** request to page2 *without* the number in the submitted data.